# Joomla! 3.6.4 router.php for a custom component

Tags: component, custom-component, joomla-3.6, jroute

I am developing a custom component for Joomla! for the first time and I am stuck on the creation of a router.php. I alredy read the [Joomla! Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component) but without clearly understand what to do.

Actually, the link to the single view of my component is:

```
index.php?option=com_layadvisory&view=layadvisory&id={$dataItem->id}
```

But I want the user to display OR:

```
www.mysite.com/Lay-Advisory/1
```

OR:

```
www.mysite.com/Lay-Advisory/person/1
```

Where 1 is the ID of the selected person. I know that I must create the build(&$query) and the parse($segments) function, but I can't understand how. Is there anyone that can direct me to the right path to follow? Thank you.

P.S. $dataItem->id is pulled from $this->data (via a foreach loop).

**UPDATE:**

I managed to get this result:

```
www.mysite.com/Lay-Advisory/id-Name-of-the-person
```

But when I go on the details/single page of the component, this notice appears:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in components\com_layadvisory\router.php

My **router.php** is

```
 * @copyright  2016 RCPSG
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JLoader::registerPrefix('Layadvisory', JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_layadvisory/');

/**
 * Class LayadvisoryRouter
 *
 * @since  3.3
 */
class LayadvisoryRouter extends JComponentRouterBase
{
    /**
     * Build method for URLs
     * This method is meant to transform the query parameters into a more human
     * readable form. It is only executed when SEF mode is switched on.
     *
     * @param   array  &$query  An array of URL arguments
     *
     * @return  array  The URL arguments to use to assemble the subsequent URL.
     *
     * @since   3.3
     */
    public function build(&$query)
    {
         $segments = array();

  if (isset($query['view'])) {
//$segments[] = $query['view'];
     unset($query['view']);

  } 

  if(isset($query['id']))                               
  {
    $segments[] = $query['id']."-".$query['name'];
    unset($query['id']);
    unset($query['name']);  
  }
  return $segments;
}

    /**
     * Parse method for URLs
     * This method is meant to transform the human readable URL back into
     * query parameters. It is only executed when SEF mode is switched on.
     *
     * @param   array  &$segments  The segments of the URL to parse.
     *
     * @return  array  The URL attributes to be used by the application.
     *
     * @since   3.3
     */
    public function parse(&$segments)
    {
$vars = array();
  $vars['view'] = "layadvisory";    
  $aux = explode(":",$segments[0]);     
  $vars['id'] = $aux[0];    
  return $vars;

    }
}
```

My **JRoute link** is:

```
$link = JRoute::_( "index.php?option=com_layadvisory&view=layadvisory&id={$dataItem->id}&name={$dataItem->name}" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking the existence of parameter name before using it. Hence PHP shows the notice message. Change your code to

```
if(isset($query['id']) && isset($query['name']))                               
{
  $segments[] = $query['id']."-".$query['name'];
  unset($query['id']);
  unset($query['name']);  
}
else if(isset($query['id']))                               
{
  $segments[] = $query['id'];
  unset($query['id']);
}
```

else block is optional, based on your requirement and design.